# ¿Como unir dos consultas ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle

Necesito unir 2 consultas en una sola, la consulta que tengo es la siguiente:

```
    SELECT TOTAL_NACIONAL,
       TOTAL_EXITOSO_NACIONAL,
       TOTAL_NOEXITOSO_NACIONAL,
       ROUND ( ( (TOTAL_EXITOSO_NACIONAL / TOTAL_NACIONAL) * 100), 2) TASA
  FROM (
                SELECT *
                    FROM (
                                SELECT COUNT (STATUS) AS TOTAL_NACIONAL,
                                    SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_EXITOSO_NACIONAL,
                                    SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_NOEXITOSO_NACIONAL
                                FROM VAS.CDR_DATA_USSD
                                    WHERE HORAINICIO >= TO_DATE ('17/03/2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
                                        AND HORAINICIO <= TO_DATE ('17/03/2019 23:59:59','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
                                        AND CODIGOSERVICIO <> 111
                                        AND CAUSATERMINO IN ('0', '-20', '-16', '-21', '-28')
                            )
                )
```

Y esta es la otra consulta que necesito agregar:

```
SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_EXITOSO_NACIONAL_SIN_CONDICION,
                        SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_NOEXITOSO_NACIONAL_SIN_CONDICION
                            FROM VAS.CDR_DATA_USSD
                                WHERE HORAINICIO >= TO_DATE ('17/03/2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
                                    AND HORAINICIO <= TO_DATE ('17/03/2019 23:59:59','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
                                    AND CODIGOSERVICIO <> 111
```

Si se dan cuenta es la misma consulta pero sin la condicion `CAUSATERMINO IN ('0', '-20', '-16', '-21', '-28')` Necesito sacar ahora la tasa sin esa condicion

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta. Si la 1ª es igual que la 2ª **excepto** la condición que indicas, no hay que *unir* nada, basta con usar directamente la 1ª consulta O_o

Comment: Si eso es lo que quiero, como lo podria hacer ?

Comment: Porque necesito sacar otra tasa pero sin esa condicion, me explico ?

Comment: No entiendo que queres unir. Como dijo Trauma, es la primer consulta, mas alla de las condiciones.

Comment: Alex, es mucho más fácil pasarnos el dataset (con phpMyAdmin, opción Exportar) y escribir el resultado que te gustaría obtener para esos datos de ejemplo que nos pases. Con eso, tus intentos y las explicaciones, seguro que damos con ello. Ánimo, que casi lo tienes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no te entendí mal, lo que puedes hacer es una suma y cuenta condicional por el fitro que mencionas `CAUSATERMINO IN ('0', '-20', '-16', '-21', '-28')`:

```
SELECT  COUNT(CAUSATERMINO IN ('0', '-20', '-16', '-21', '-28') THEN STATUS ELSE NULL END)                AS TOTAL_NACIONAL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 AND CAUSATERMINO IN ('0', '-20', '-16', '-21', '-28') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_EXITOSO_NACIONAL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 0 AND CAUSATERMINO IN ('0', '-20', '-16', '-21', '-28') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_NOEXITOSO_NACIONAL,
        -- Ahora totales sin la condición original
        COUNT (STATUS)                                                                                    AS TOTAL_NACIONAL_2,
        SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)                                                      AS TOTAL_EXITOSO_NACIONAL_2,
        SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)                                                      AS TOTAL_NOEXITOSO_NACIONAL_2
    FROM VAS.CDR_DATA_USSD
    WHERE   HORAINICIO >= TO_DATE ('17/03/2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
            AND HORAINICIO <= TO_DATE ('17/03/2019 23:59:59','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
            AND CODIGOSERVICIO <> 111
```

Detalle:

- Estamos modificando solo la subconsulta para agregar 3 nuevas columnas
- Quitamos de `WHERE` la condición original
- Modificamos las funciones de agregación para que actúen en función de la condición  `CAUSATERMINO IN ('0', '-20', '-16', '-21', '-28')` para las tres primeras columnas y las tres siguiente sin esta condición.

Comment: Gracias me funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Si te he entendido bien, lo que quieres es sacar la consulta que ya tienes, junto a la nueva tasa, que es igual pero sin esa condición.

Yo utilizaría un procedimiento almacenado. Dentro del procedimiento puedes hacer las dos consultas por separado y asignarlas a variables distintas, para luego devolverlas como resultado.

[Aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm) tienes más información al respecto sobre como se hace en Oracle. Básicamente, defines los parámetros de entrada que te varíen entre consultas en el procedimiento almacenado y los parámetros de salida serían *TOTAL_NACIONAL, TOTAL_EXITOSO_NACIONAL, TOTAL_NOEXITOSO_NACIONAL, ...* Dentro realizas la primera consulta para calcular la tasa original y la segunda para la tasa sin condición. Tienes que meterlas en las variables definidas en el `RETURN` .

Los procedimientos almacenados son muy útiles, ya que te permiten hacer varios cálculos encadenados o no, y devolverlos en una sola consulta.

Comment: Voy a probarlo, gracias por la respuesta